# Deploying a node.js app (discord.jd bot) on Heroku causing an error

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I'm trying to deploy a discord bot on heroku. It **works** for about 1-2 minutes and then **there is an error**:

```
2020-08-10T10:05:17.228802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-08-10T10:05:17.246146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-08-10T10:05:17.307500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-08-10T10:05:17.347445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

(complete log):

```
2020-08-10T10:04:19.372794+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-10T10:04:19.372804+00:00 app[web.1]: > arepee-bot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-08-10T10:04:19.372804+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2020-08-10T10:04:19.372804+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-08-10T10:04:20.468443+00:00 app[web.1]: Bot [welcomeMessage.js] is ready!
2020-08-10T10:04:30.643838+00:00 app[web.1]: Bot [index.js] is ready!
2020-08-10T10:05:17.228802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-08-10T10:05:17.246146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-08-10T10:05:17.307500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2020-08-10T10:05:17.347445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

the `start` command in the `package.json` is: `node index.js`

the Procfile is:

```
worker: node index.js
```

and `index.js` is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const welcomeMessage = require("./welcomeMessage")

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot [index.js] is ready!")
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

I also have another file, `welcomeMessage`:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot [welcomeMessage.js] is ready!")
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

    let welcomeChannel = client.channels.cache.get('0000000000000')

    welcomeChannel.send("hello world")
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

What causes this peoblem? thx

Answer (score 1):

Man, somehow I did here, first time ever a random try worked for me, I'm so happy! Look, I hope it will work for you too. First of all, go see your "`package.json`" file, inside it you must have the:

```
"scripts": {
    
  },
```

You should put the "`start" : "node index.js`" there (even if there's already another things inside 'scripts', but don't delete the other stuff, just add this one) it will be like that:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
  },
```

Then go to your Procfile and change the "`worker : node index.js`" to "`worker npm start`" (I tried it because I notice only web was working and the command of it was "web npm start")

It should solve the problem!

I'm pretty sure that it was what solved for me, now it's running non-stop, but if it's not what solved, I also used some commands on the Terminal, the commands: "`heroku run worker`", also "`heroku ps:scale worker=1`".

I hope it will help you, I was 8 hours straight trying to make it work because I had other errors, and I know how annoying is this thing not working.

Obs.: also you need to do what the other person said before:

> "(...) you need to disable the web dyno and enable the worker dyno".

PS.: I know you already did the start thing, I'm just thinking if someone get here without this information maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you need to disable the web dyno and enable the worker dyno.